# always showing time in message headers of mail

Tags: mail.app

I have my inbox messages sorted by date, and unthreaded.  For mail received today it shows the time the message was received.  But for earlier messages, it only says "yesterday" or the actual date but not the time.

How can I get it to also show the time for all past e-mails?